# How to update a single item in FlatList in React Native?

Tags: react-native

**Attention**: I have posted an answer down there, personally I think it's the best solution so far. Even though it's not the highest rated answer, but based on the result I'm getting, it is very efficient.

---------------------------------------------**Original Question**-------------------------------------------------------

Suppose I am writing a Twitter clone, but much simpler. I put each item in FlatList and render them.

To "like" a post, I press the "like" button on the post and the "like" button turns red, I press it again, it turns gray.

This is what I have so far: I store all the loaded posts in `this.state`, each post has a property called "liked", which is boolean, indicating whether this user has liked this post or not, when user presses "like", I go to `state.posts` and update the `liked` property of that post, and then use `this.setState` to update posts like so:

```
// 1. FlatList
<FlatList
    ...
    data={this.state.posts}
    renderItem={this.renderPost}
    ...
/> 

// 2. renderPost
renderPost({ item, index }) {
    return (
        <View style={someStyle}>
            ... // display other properties of the post
            // Then display the "like" button
            <Icon
                name='favorite'
                size={25}
                color={item.liked ? 'red' : 'gray'}
                containerStyle={someStyle}
                iconStyle={someStyle}
                onPress={() => this.onLikePost({ item, index })}
            />
            ...
        </View>
    );
}

// 3. onLikePost
likePost({ item, index }) {
    let { posts } = this.state;
    let targetPost = posts[index];

    // Flip the 'liked' property of the targetPost
    targetPost.liked = !targetPost.liked;

    // Then update targetPost in 'posts'
    posts[index] = targetPost;

    // Then reset the 'state.posts' property
    this.setState({ posts });
}
```

This approach works, however, it is too slow. The color of the "like" button flips as I press it, but it usually takes about 1 second before the color changes. What I want is that the color would flip almost at the same time when I press it.

I do know why this would happen, I should probably not use `this.setState`, because when I do that, the `posts` state changed, and all posts get re-rendered, but what other approach can I try?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't get me wrong, @ShubhnikSingh's answer did help, but I retracted it because I found a better solution to this question, long time ago, and finally I remembered to post it here.

Suppose my post item contains these properties:

```
{
    postId: "-L84e-aHwBedm1FHhcqv",
    date: 1525566855,
    message: "My Post",
    uid: "52YgRFw4jWhYL5ulK11slBv7e583",
    liked: false,
    likeCount: 0,
    commentCount: 0
}
```

Where `liked` represents whether the user viewing this post has liked this post, which will determine the color of the "like" button (by default, it's gray, but red if `liked == true`)

---

Here are the steps to recreate my solution: make "Post" a `Component` and render it in a `FlatList`. You can use React's `PureComponent` if you don't have any props that you pass to your `Post` such as an array or object that can be deceptively not shallow equal. If you don't know what that means, just use a regular `Component` and override `shouldComponentUpdate` as we do below.

```
class Post extends Component {                                                      
  // This determines whether a rendered post should get updated                     
  // Look at the states here, what could be changing as time goes by?               
  // Only 2 properties: "liked" and "likeCount", if the person seeing               
  // this post ever presses the "like" button                                       
  // This assumes that, unlike Twitter, updates do not come from other              
  // instances of the application in real time.                                     
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {                                     
    const { liked, likeCount } = nextProps                                          
    const { liked: oldLiked, likeCount: oldLikeCount } = this.props                 

    // If "liked" or "likeCount" is different, then update                          
    return liked !== oldLiked || likeCount !== oldLikeCount                         
  }                                                                                 

  render() {                                                                        
    return (                                                                        
      <View>                                                                        
        {/* ...render other properties */}                                          
        <TouchableOpacity                                                           
          onPress={() => this.props.onPressLike(this.props.postId)}                 
        >                                                                           
          <Icon name="heart" color={this.props.liked ? 'gray' : 'red'} />           
        </TouchableOpacity>                                                         
      </View>                                                                       
    )                                                                               
  }                                                                                 
}
```

---

Then, create a `PostList` component that will be in charge of handling the logic for loading posts and handling like interactions:

```
class PostList extends Component {                                                        

/**                                                                                       
 * As you can see, we are not storing "posts" as an array. Instead,                       
 * we make it a JSON object. This allows us to access a post more concisely               
 * than if we stores posts as an array. For example:                                      
 *                                                                                        
 * this.state.posts as an array                                                           
 * findPost(postId) {                                                                     
 *   return this.state.posts.find(post => post.id === postId)                             
 * }                                                                                      
 * findPost(postId) {                                                                     
 *   return this.state.posts[postId]                                                      
 * }                                                                                      
 * a specific post by its "postId", you won't have to iterate                             
 * through the whole array, you can just call "posts[postId]"                             
 * to access it immediately:                                                              
 * "posts": {                                                                             
 *     "<post_id_1>": { "message": "", "uid": "", ... },                                  
 *     "<post_id_2>": { "message": "", "uid": "", ... },                                  
 *     "<post_id_3>": { "message": "", "uid": "", ... }                                   
 * }                                                                                      
 * FlatList wants an array for its data property rather than an object,                   
 * so we need to pass data={Object.values(this.state.posts)} rather than                  
 * just data={this.state.posts} as one might expect.                                      
*/                                                                                        

  state = {                                                                                 
    posts: {}                                                                               
    // Other states                                                                         
  }                                                                                         

  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    const { date, message, uid, postId, other, props, here } = item
    return (
      <Post
        date={date}
        message={message}
        uid={uid}
        onPressLike={this.handleLikePost}
      />
    )
  }

  handleLikePost = postId => {
    let post = this.state.posts[postId]
    const { liked, likeCount } = post

    const newPost = {
      ...post,
      liked: !liked,
      likeCount: liked ? likeCount - 1 : likeCount + 1
    }

    this.setState({
      posts: {
        ...this.state.posts,
        [postId]: newPost
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={Object.values(this.state.posts)}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={({ item }) => item.postId}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

**In summary:**

1) Write a custom component (`Post`) for rendering each item in "FlatList"

2) Override the "shouldComponentUpdate" of the custom component (`Post`) function to tell the component when to update

Handle the "state of likes" in a parent component (`PostList`) and pass data down to each child

Comment: this tips does not work for me, could you please help how can I find a good solutions, becuase when I update a single item of flatlist all items get re-renders and if I use your solutions on that time nothing will update

Comment: @IqbalJan have you found a solution that only renders the updated item?

Comment: Do you PLEASE HAVE the SOURCE CODE FOR THIS?

Answer (score 21):

You can set `extraData` in `FlatList`:

```
<FlatList
...
    extraData={this.state}
    data={this.state.posts}
    renderItem={this.renderPost}
    ...
/>
```

When `state.posts` or `state.posts`'s item change, `FlatList` will re-render.

From [FlatList#extradata](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#extradata):

> A marker property for telling the list to re-render (since it implements PureComponent). If any of your renderItem, Header, Footer, etc. functions depend on anything outside of the data prop, stick it here and treat it immutably.

#### Update:

Functional component implementation:

```js
export default function() {
    // list of your data
    const [list, setList] = React.useState([])
    const [extraData, setExtraData] = React.useState(new Date())

    // some update on the item of list[idx]
    const someAction = (idx)=>{
        list[idx].show = 1
        setList(list)
        setExtraData(new Date())
    }
    return (
        <FlatList
            // ...
            data={list}
            extraData={extraData}
        />
    )
}
```

After updating `list`, I use `setExtraData(new Date())` to tell the `FlatList` to re-render. Because the new time is different from the previous.

Comment: this is also a good way to listen for changes to update flatlist. thx @tomfriwel

Comment: Hey @tomfriwel I've faced the same issue and I already add `extraData` but I can't see anything on the screen! and I'm sure my `data` is contained the data from the server cuz when i log data In Render() i see them !

Comment: @DevAS Is `extraData={this.state}`, not `extraData={this.state.data}` ?

Comment: @tomfriwel it's `extraData={this.state}`

Comment: @DevAS It's really hard for me to see the problem without the code.

Comment: Here's @tomfriwel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57595796/how-to-force-flatlist-to-re-render-after-getting-a-single-data/57620661#57620661

Comment: this re-renders all the items in  the list. I thought the question is how to change a single item in the list. can anyone please provide a full working example with code to demonstrate a single item change?

Answer (score 9):

If you are testing on android than try turning off the developer mode. Or are you hitting some API and updating the post on the server and updating the like button in UI corresponding to the server response? If that is the case do tell me, I too have encountered this and I solved it. Also I have commented the second last line in your code which isn't needed.

```
// 1. FlatList
<FlatList
    ...
    data={this.state.posts}
    renderItem={this.renderPost}
    ...
/> 

// 2. renderPost
renderPost({ item, index }) {
    return (
        <View style={someStyle}>
            ... // display other properties of the post
            // Then display the "like" button
            <Icon
                name='favorite'
                size={25}
                color={item.liked ? 'red' : 'gray'}
                containerStyle={someStyle}
                iconStyle={someStyle}
                onPress={() => this.onLikePost({ item, index })}
            />
            ...
        </View>
    );
}

// 3. onLikePost
likePost({ item, index }) {
    let { posts } = this.state;
    let targetPost = posts[index];

    // Flip the 'liked' property of the targetPost
    targetPost.liked = !targetPost.liked;

    // Then update targetPost in 'posts'
    // You probably don't need the following line.
    // posts[index] = targetPost;

    // Then reset the 'state.posts' property
    this.setState({ posts });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am not listening to the server change. I update the `liked` property in database in background, but I know that would take some amount of time, therefore, I have to give user an immediate feedback, which is why I update the `liked` property of that post and use `this.setState` to change the post locally first. Actually after the `this.setState({ posts })` line, I went ahead to update the record in database, I forgot to write that down in my question, sorry about that. I don't know why it would take about 1 second to update the post

Comment: If you are doing the setState before the database operations than it should do it quickly. Can you paste a little bit of more code that is involved?

Comment: You're right, I tried to modify the database before doing the setState, I thought that was an async operation, so it wouldn't matter which operation I do first. Now the color changes almost immediately

Comment: You should also handle the situation like this:
1) You hit the like button and update the UI.
2) If While updating the entry in database you encountered an error.
3) Then you should undo the update in UI too.