# How to Re-Render just one item inside Flatlist?

Tags: firebase, react-native, flatlist

I have a flatlist full of posts, and I have a like system where I like one post, I would like for that post (aka item in a flatlist) re render but not entire screen and not entire flatlist so I see like count updated. I want it like Facebook where you like a post and simply that post now has one more like. All this is stored in a firestore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update a single item in FlatList in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46994262/how-to-update-a-single-item-in-flatlist-in-react-native)

Comment: I was looking at it prior, the case scenario is extremely similar to mine, but the answer is very complicated and would make me change many things in my app so im curious is there some easier solution without so much needing to change.